# Light Adwaita theme for Ubuntu Unity - toolbar customization!

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, themes, gtk

[image: snap1]

The above snapshot shows some application windows: Nautilus, Rhythmbox, gedit using the Adwaita theme on Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity). I've made changes in `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/*` but that doesn't seem to change the main-toolbar of the windows, and it doesn't look consistent with the theme color settings as you should see in the picture. The `gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file contains just the line:

> @import url("resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main.css");

Is there a way I could view this `resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main.css` ? (Tried to browse with Nautilus, which got it to crash..) Is it that Adwaita uses binary for this? I've read a tutorial on how to edit (was that only for gtk 3 ?!) but couldn't.

How can I customize Adwaita theme's toolbar in Ubuntu 12.04 Unity so as to make it look consistent with the title bar?

Or, is there an alternate way to create css files for such windows?

Comment: i'm not positive but to change the toolbar icons, you may just need to change the icon theme

Answer (score 1):

The resource file in question is in fact binary, but can be unpacked with a program called gresource-extract.sh
You can find it here:
http://projects.thecodergeek.com/scripts/gresource-extract
Once you unpack it, the text files can be edited. Just remember to change the files that pointed to the binary so that they point to the unpacked versions.